# Why kotlin File class has no close method?

Tags: kotlin

I've been reading [KotlinDoc for the stdlib/kotlin.io.File class](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/-file/). But I can't see any mention of a close() method nor an autocloseable feature : so what is really happening when a File instance get garbage collected ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`java.io.File` (there is no `kolin.io.File` at the moment) is not something you can close. See official docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, as I was used to direct java, I forgot that Kotlin simplifies us the life by reading content directly from File class, and not a Reader subclass. BTW, what is happening over the hood when I use the extension File.writeText() extension : does it creates a Reader instance and handle closing for us ?

Comment: Yes. You can look it up in the sources: there's a link on this page http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/-file/write-text.html.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a real class, this is a list of Extension-Methods for the java.io.File class.

See: [Extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to look at the page "Extensions" word. Also, I forgot that the File class is not a Reader subclass.